# Securing a basement suite with door to main floor

Tags: doors, lock, security

I live in a basement suite and the door to the main floor has a lock on the landlords side.

Is there a simple way to secure it from my side?

Comment: How about a hook and eye?

Comment: I thought of that and mentioned it to the landlord and he didn’t like the idea. Said he didn’t wants holes in the casing or the door

Comment: Did you ask him to tell you what method he would approve of in order for  you to   address your desire for a way to secure the door ?

Comment: Could you describe how the door is situated? Does the door swing toward your side or to the landlord's main floor side? Is the door at a landing, top of stairs or bottom of stairs? Answers to these may be lead to some plausible suggestions.

Comment: No he said that they would not enter our apartment without giving us notice first. Which they have been very good with when needing to access the furnace room/storage space. But we are going away for a couple of weeks and want to secure the door. Was just trying to come up with a simple solution.

Comment: Micheal Kara the door open inward to our unit. It is a the bottom of the stairs located in their side.

Comment: How about a Doberman?

Comment: Lee Sam -Lol If only that was an option

Comment: What about a nanny cam? Many are easily hidden if they enter the residence you will have proof. Some can even connect to the internet so you can check while away , we have motion activated cameras in our tac rooms  after posting notices none of the borders equipment has disappeared.

Comment: TBH, if you're going to be gone for a week or more and there are utilities located in your apartment for the whole building, locking your side of the access to prevent the landlord from entering could be detrimental to _your_ possessions. What if there a pipe bursts and they can't get in to shut off the water? You're in the basement and it floods all of _your_ stuff! I'd second the motion activated "nanny cam" for while you're gone if you have reason to suspect the landlord is up to no good, then I'd suggest looking for a new place to live.

Answer (score 0):

Try this door wedge for when you’re home:

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=door+wedge+stopper&sprefix=door+wedge&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_10

Try this for when you are away. It’s a hassle for you to install each time you Leave:

[https://www.amazon.com/Defender-Security-Lock-Out-Diecast-Construction/dp/B00CGYNFF0/ref=mp_s_a_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=door+lock+out+box&qid=1592690322&sr=8-7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CGYNFF0)

Or this type when you’re away:

[https://www.amazon.com/August-Wi-Fi-Smart-Generation-Silver/dp/B082VXK9CK/ref=mp_s_a_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=door+lock+out+box&qid=1592690322&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082VXK9CK)